# How can I use item

Tags: keystonejs

I don't know how to access the `item` object in **KeystoneJS 6**.

I have 5 lists:

- `User`
- `Blog`
- `Post`
- `Comment`
- `Label`

Let's focus on the `Blog` list. I want to only allow a `User` to *update* and *delete* his/her `Blog` if he/she owns it. I also want a `Post` to only be created for the `Blog` that is owned by the current `User`.

How can I approach that in KeystoneJS 6?

I tried to implement something like this:

```
const blogBelongsToUser = ({ session, item }) => {}
```

But I was not successful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `access` field in the schema.

```js
const Blog = new keystone.List('Blog', {
  access: ({ authentication: { item: user } }) => ({
    create: user ? true : false,
    read: true,
    update: user ? user.id === blog.author : false,
    delete: user ? user.id === blog.author : false,
  }),
});
```